# remove font-awesome from landing page of site (Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fontawesome-4.4.0

In my header.php file, I only want to load the font-awesome css file if the page is **not** my main page (it is costing 1 sec of load time and barely does anything).
The following code in the `<head>` html part, does not work:

````
<?php if ( !is_home() ){ ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<?php } ?>```
````

Comment: My load time for this file is 16 ms. How can it be 1 sec on your computer? It's only 6 KB.

Comment: Would take ~1s on 56k dial up...

Comment: Have you also tried `is_front_page()` ? Check here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224592/if-is-home-is-front-page

Comment: ^ maybe you ought to use `is_front_page` instead

Comment: It is loading both font-awesome and fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0. The latter takes a good second for the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to target the site Front Page, you need to use is_front_page(). The is_home() conditional returns true when the blog posts index is displayed, which may or may not be on the site Front Page.

```
<?php if ( !is_front_page() ){ ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<?php } ?>
```

Second, you need to hook your function into an appropriate hook, which it appears, in this case, is wp_enqueue_scripts.

```
function rf_enqueue_front_page_scripts() {
    if( !is_front_page() )
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'font-swesome', "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rf_enqueue_front_page_scripts' );
```